# Vector Field/Differential Equation Correspondence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen some examples (though I am currently looking for a good rigorous explanation and a source would be much appreciated) of taking a second order linear ODE and turning it into a linear system of 2 equations.  My question is, can you go the other way?  That is, given some continuous vector field, can we find a differential equation corresponding to it (of any order)?

Thanks!

Comment: most differential equations books that ive seen show the solvability of $n$th order linear odes by making a system (and prove existence theorems for systems of first order linear eqns). just create a variable for each derivative, i.e. $x^{(n)}=x_n$ so most of the eqns in the system just look like $x_n=x'_{n-1}$  (not addressing your actual question)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to go from and linear system to a single equation (of any order) ?

Comment: I mean that for first order and second order ODE's we can get vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the first is just a direction field, the second by some massaging, making $y'$ the vertical axis and $y$ the horizontal axis, I believe).  However, given a vector field, is it always a solution to some differential equation, of some kind?  Can we find that equation?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- indeed, you likely mean a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Assuming that's the case, the answer is that if the vector field $\vec{V}(x,y) = v_1(x,y)\hat{i} + v_2(x,y)\hat{j}$ obeys "The Canonical Flip on the Double Tangent Bundle" -- that is to say, if $v_1(x,y) = y$ -- then $\ddot{x} = v_2(x, \dot{x})$ is the second-order ordinary differential equation corresponding to $\vec{V}$.

(For an explanation of the correspondence between ODEs and vector fields, try [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://smile.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-MIT-Press/dp/0262510189) by Arnold. Also, many introductory texts on differential manifolds discuss how tangent vector field are [first-order] ODEs on manifolds; I prefer [*Differential Manifolds*](https://smile.amazon.com/Differential-Manifolds-Pure-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0124218504/) by Kosinski.

To understand The Canonical Flip on the Double Tangent Bundle, I recommend [*Transversal Mappings and Flows*](https://smile.amazon.com/Transversal-Mappings-Flows-Ralph-Abraham-ebook/dp/B001C6J1AG/) by Abraham and Robbin  and [*The Geometry of Jet Bundles*](https://smile.amazon.com/Geometry-Bundles-Mathematical-Society-Lecture-ebook/dp/B01DM26TOI/) by Saunders.)